# Python provided Feedback Transfer function is not matching with the manually computed Transfer Function

Tags: control-theory, python

I am new to Control Theory and started learning it recently. I am following **Modern Control Engineering by Ogata**. I have come across the **Obtaining Cascaded, Parallel, and Feedback Transfer Functions with MATLAB** Section. Below is the diagram for serial, parallel, and Feedback Transfer functions.

[image: Block Diagram for serial, parallel, and Feedback Transfer functions]

In this, if I take two systems

```
>>> sys1

      10
--------------
s^2 + 2 s + 10
>>> sys2

  5
-----
s + 5
```

For series(a) transfer function, the result would be `G1(s) X G2(s)`.

For the below python program,

```
import control
sys1 =  control.tf([10],[1,2,10]) # Equivalent to G1(s)
sys2 = control.tf([5],[1,5])      # Equivalent to G2(s)
series_sys = control.series(sys1,sys2)
print(series_sys)
```

I get this output

```
          50
-----------------------
s^3 + 7 s^2 + 20 s + 50
```

This output is matching with my hand calculations.

If I try the same thing with parallel transfer functions, the output is matching with `G1(s)+G2(s)`

```
>>> control.parallel(sys1,sys2)

  5 s^2 + 20 s + 100
-----------------------
s^3 + 7 s^2 + 20 s + 50
```

But for the Feedback Transfer functions, the output is not matching with  `G1(s)/{1+[G1(s) X G2(s)]}` (This is the resultant Transfer function for feedback systems, or is my understanding is wrong ? )

If I calculate the transfer function for this using python, I get the below output. I have compared this with `Octave`. The results in both are the same.

```
>>> control.feedback(sys1 , sys2)

        10 s + 50
------------------------
s^3 + 7 s^2 + 20 s + 100
```

But if I calculate the transfer function using the above formula, I am getting the following result:

```
        10 s^3 + 70 s^2 + 200 s + 500
---------------------------------------------
s^5 + 9 s^4 + 44 s^3 + 210 s^2 + 400 s + 1000
```

I am doing anything wrong, or is my understanding of the feedback transfer function wrong?

Kindly help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{10 s^3 + 70 s^2 + 200 s + 500}{s^5 + 9 s^4 + 44 s^3 + 210 s^2 + 400 s + 1000} = \frac{(10 s + 50)\cancel{(s^2 + 2s + 10)}}{(s^3 + 7 s^2 + 20 s + 100)\cancel{(s^2 + 2s + 10)}}
$$

What you see happens because of numeric inaccuracy so the pole/zero cancellation is not done.

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb for not factorizing the numerator and denominator.